# Update date, increment by year, for all records by ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I have data like this:

```
create table t (PID int identity,
                        AwardDate date,
                        PytUnits int,
                        PytDate date,
                        AwardID int);

insert into t values 
('1/1/2014', '5', '1/1/2014', 1),
('1/1/2014', '5', '1/1/2015', 1),
('1/1/2014', '5', '1/1/2016', 1),
('1/1/2014', '5', '1/1/2012', 2),
('1/1/2014', '5', '1/1/2013', 2),
('1/1/2014', '5', '1/1/2014', 2),
('1/1/2014', '5', '1/1/2015', 2)
;
```

[(see this in SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0dfaa/3)

How can I update the `PytDate`, if it is `> Today's date`, to the first day of the next month for the first record, and for each record after that increase the year by 1, per `AwardID`?

**Important:** the database is actually MS Access, however I the Fiddle is on SQL server to use as an example and hopefully generate an answer I can run with and convert to Access SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TSQL the simplest way is to use a Common Table Expression. However MSAccess does not have this feature. So the TSQL below, whilst it works in SQL Server 2008 and above will not work in MSaccess. If you need an MSAccess query to do this then let me know. It may be simpler to create a Sub Routine that does it.

```
;with Awards(NewDate, RowID, AwardRowId, PID,
                            AwardDate ,
                            PytUnits,
                            PytDate ,
                            AwardID )    --CTE Syntax set up columns
    as
    (select NewDate = case when PytDate> getdate() then convert(varchar(7), convert(date, dateadd(month, 1, getdate())))+'-01' else PytDate end   --Generate a new date based on the rules provided in question i.e. for future dates use next month, this is temporary value as we override it in the output if the other rule is met this row is only used for the first row
    , RowID = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by PID)  --RowID is simple row number for each row of output based on PID which is Primary key
    , AwardRowId = DENSE_Rank() over (order by AwardId) --Generate a RowID based on AwardId for each change in AwardID as it comes to us
    , *  --all other columns
    FROM t where PytDate> getdate()  --we are only interested in future dated data
     )
    Select CalcDate = case RowID   
        when 1 then NewDate                                 --first row is special use the next month value
        else dateadd(year, AwardRowId,     AwardDate) end   --other rows get a new date based on the row position by Award and we add a year for each change in AwardId to the base award date
    , * 
    from Awards
    order by PID
```

If you wish to simulate this in MSaccess you can create 4 queries which chain this logic together

Query1 - Gets the FirstOfNextMonth as Simple Calculation and Finds Future Records
Query2 - Gets LIST OF AWARDS
Query3 - generate DenseRank
Query4 - Results

Query1
    SELECT t.*, IIf([pytdate]>Now(),DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m",1,[PYTDATE])),Month(DateAdd("m",1,[PYTDATE])),1),[PYTDATE]) AS FirstOfMonth, [pytdate]>Now() AS IsFuture
    FROM t
    WHERE (((t.PytDate)>Now()));

Query2
    SELECT Query1.AwardID
    FROM Query1
    GROUP BY Query1.AwardID
    ORDER BY Query1.AwardID;

Query3
    SELECT A.AwardId, Count(*) AS dense_rank
    FROM query2 AS A LEFT JOIN query2 AS B ON B.AwardId<=A.AwardId
    GROUP BY A.AwardId;

Query4
    SELECT Query1.*, IIf([dense_rank]=1,[FirstOfMonth],DateAdd("yyyy",[dense_rank],[pytdate])) AS NewDate, Query3.dense_rank
    FROM Query1 INNER JOIN Query3 ON Query1.AwardID=Query3.AwardId
    ORDER BY Query3.dense_rank, Query1.PytDate;

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it really helped me string some of the logic together. That being said, do you think you could add some notes to your answer that explains the `TSQL` code? I've been looking at it, piece by piece, but it may be beneficial to have here also.